# Разбить строку по регулярному выражению

Tags: php

Есть такая строка:

```
[m1]текст 1[/m][m2]текст 2[/m][m3]текст 3[/m]
```

Мне нужно получить массив:

```
0 => текст 1
1 => текст 2
2 => текст 3
```

нужно разбить именно по тегам **[m(n)]**...**[/m]** где (n) любое число

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: например
[так](https://regex101.com/r/kVy199/1) ЗЫ так как тело сообщения должно содержать 30 символов минимум, то надо еще написать букав

Answer (score 0):

Тут не то чтобы разбивать надо, а просто вытащить данные. При неоходимости, можно `mX` ключами сделать (если,  конечно, повторов нет).

```
$str = "[m1]текст 1[/m][m2]текст 2[/m][m3]текст 3[/m]";
preg_match_all("#\[(m\d+)](.*?)\[/m]#", $str, $m);

$result = array_combine($m[1], $m[2]);

print_r($result);
```

получите

```
[m1] => текст 1
[m2] => текст 2
[m3] => текст 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Решений у задачи великое множество, наиболее простые из которых будут разбиение по тэгам, с последующим отбрасыванием пустот, либо использование Unicode регулярных выражений.

```php
$s = '[m1]текст 1[/m][m2]текст 2[/m][m3]текст 3[/m]';
// первый вариант
$result = array_values(array_filter(preg_split('/\[.+?\]/', $s)));
print_r($result);
// второй варинат
preg_match_all('/\p{Cyrillic}*\s+\d+/ui', $s, $result);
print_r($result[0]);
```